# How to resolve "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file" when output results to file?

Tags: python-2.7, output, sha256

I have a piece of code that converting email addresses to HASH using SHA256 algorithm. When running the code, the expected results are presented, but when i'm trying to output the results - i'm getting an error :
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

```
import os
import hashlib

with open("emails.txt", "r") as text:
    for line in text.readlines():
        line = line.rstrip("\n")

        m = hashlib.sha256(line)
        print(m.hexdigest())

with open("Output.txt", "w") as text_file:
    for row in text:
        print row
        text_file.write("%s\n" % str(row))
```

can anyone help me to get all the results to external file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the line `for row in text:`, you are trying to loop over `text` which at this point in the script is a closed file. You could structure the code as such:

```
import os
import hashlib

with open("emails.txt", "r") as text:
    with open("Output.txt", "w") as text_file:
        for line in text.readlines():
            line = line.rstrip("\n")
            m = hashlib.sha256(line.encode()).hexdigest() 
            print m
            print line
            text_file.write("%s:%s\n" % (str(line), m))
```

Comment: Hi Matt, now I'm getting the email addresses in the "email.txt" file to the "Output.txt" file - I need just the hash values to be written to the "Output.txt" file.

Comment: Hi Yos, I've updated the code to reflect it, let me know

Comment: The following error is displayed: TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Comment: This is how the output to the file is looks like: mmm.fff@gmail.com:<built-in method hexdigest of _hashlib.HASH object at 0x058194F8>

Comment: Try the following (I've edited again) also if any of this helps, don't forget to upvote the answer or mark as accepted! Thanks :)

Comment: Glad to help :)